# Endothermic reaction of solid ammonium nitrate

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image: Dissolution of ammonium nitrate in water]

The above process is **endothermic** by mixing water. When the products (solution containing $\ce{NH4+}$ ions and $\ce{NO3-}$ ions) are heated up again, will it form back $\ce{NH4NO3}$ (solid ammonium nitrate) that is the original reactant?

Comment: I would be careful about heating an ammonium nitrate solution sufficient to drive off the water as solid ammonium nitrate is explosive. However, in principle, if you remove the water you get back solid ammonium nitrate

Comment: There is many salts with endothermic dissolution. If stable enough, they can be retained back as solid ionic matrix by spontaneous evaporation, providing the relative humidity is low enough. Heating speeds up the process but may affect the salt stability. In some cases it may lead to desintegration or explosion.

Comment: @Waylander  Hi, what about if I let the nitrate solution evaporate it in the sun, it will still give me back solid ammonium nitrate right? Thanks

Comment: @Waylander I am a high school student. Dont you think it is useful for designing an air cooling system. You just have to get some ammonium nitrate and water to cool the air. After that, the solution produced is evaporated in the sun to yield back the powder again.

Comment: @MaximusSu  Sure if you leave the solution in the sun you will get ammonium nitrate crystals back eventually. There are far more efficient ways of air cooling though.

Comment: In your high school gymnasium or medical office, they likely have packets of ammonium nitrate, with a sub-packet of water,  to make an "instant" cold compress for injuries. There are also ammonia absorption refrigerators: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_refrigerator